# How to convert a URL to an <a> tag and convert an image URL to a <img> tag in JavaScript, JQuery, or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I don't have any code to show you guys because I don't know how to do it, but what I want to do, If a person pastes a URL into a contenteditable div, it converts that links into a  tag, but if they paste an image URL into the div, it converts it to a  tag.

Is there a way to do that in PHP, JQuery, or Javascript?

Comment: Yes. There's a way to do that. You have to create you HTML codes first then you print the value from the input into the **href** of the `<a>` tag or **src** of the `<img>` tag using PHP or JavaScript ...... In **PHP** you use **echo** to print the value.... I think you should first learn the basics for these languages. Everything will be clear afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect a 'paste' event. When that happens you run a test on the string pasted to see if it matches an image (testing for the extension being one of the web image extensions), and if not that, testing for it matching a URL.

I tried allowing for multiple pastes in a contentEditable area and ran into issues. So if a one-off paste into a box is what you're looking for, this should work. If you're looking to have other content mixed in, this might be a starting point.

```js
function handlePaste(e) {
  var clipboardData, pastedData;

  // Stop data actually being pasted into div
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get pasted data via clipboard API
  clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');

  //test for image
  let formats = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp'];
  let url = pastedData.match(/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/)

  console.log(url)
  if (formats.includes(pastedData.toLowerCase().split(".").reverse()[0])) {
    //image
    e.target.innerHTML = `<img src='${pastedData}' class='eimg' />`;
  } else if (url) {
    e.target.innerHTML = `<a href='${pastedData}'>this link</a>`;
  }
}

document.querySelector('.editable').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```

```css
    .editable {
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  {
```

```html
<div contentEditable class='editable'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you paste a content into a `contenteditable div`, the div itself will automatically convert the content as following:

- If that is a url, like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68056429/how-to-convert-a-url-to-an-a-tag-and-convert-an-image-url-to-a-img-tag-in-ja`, it will be converted to  **tag**
- Image URL, like `https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png`, it will be wrapped inside a div tag
- Other content would be also wrapped in a **div tag**
- **ENTER** will be converted into

Once user pastes the content from clipboard into your div, it surely has content

In javascript, register **onblur** event for your div, and do following:

- You have to travel its children
- For each child, read its innerText
- Then convert it into what you would like

After all, put back all your converted result as the innerHTML content of the main div.

Good luck.